# Delete button for list items and strikethrough functionality (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do:

I need to make list items strikethroughable (individually) by clicking on the respective list item.

I also need to add a delete button for each list item.

The base is excercise material for a course I'm taking regarding web development. So far, I've figured out how to add a delete button after each new list item and give it an attribute. But I don't know how to add the strikethrough functionality nor the best way to make each delete button delete the parent li element. I'm looking for a solution and some guidance. Thanks in advance!

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var btnDelete = document.createElement("button");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  btnDelete.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
  // btnDelete.setAttribute("id", "buttonitem"+returnIdNumber());
  btnDelete.setAttribute("class", "delete");
  li.appendChild(btnDelete);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
}

// function listLength() {
//  return document.querySelectorAll("li").length;
// }

// function returnIdNumber() {
//  return listLength()+1;
// }

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```css
.coolTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  word-spacing: -8px;
  color: tomato;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 firebrick, -2px -2px 0 firebrick, -3px -3px 0 firebrick, -4px -4px 0 firebrick, -5px -5px 0 firebrick, -6px -6px 0 firebrick, -7px -7px 0 firebrick, -8px -8px 0 firebrick, -30px 20px 40px dimgrey;
}

.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.delete {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<p id="first">Get it done today</p>
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<ul>
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

My JavaScript so far (commented out section was a possible ID system workaround, but considered it to be an overly complicated approach, am I wrong?):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating `textnode` for input value, keep that in span. And `onclick` you can access the clicked element children like below

```
li.onclick = function() {
  var text = this.children[0].innerText.strike(); // text will will hold <strike>User Input</strike>
  this.children[0].innerHTML = text; // As there is html in text, use innerHTML
}
```

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var btnDelete = document.createElement("button");
  var inp = document.createElement("span");
  inp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  //li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  btnDelete.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
  btnDelete.setAttribute("class", "delete");
  li.appendChild(inp);
  li.appendChild(btnDelete);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
  li.onclick = function() {
    var text = this.children[0].innerText.strike();
    this.children[0].innerHTML = text;
  }
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```css
.coolTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  word-spacing: -8px;
  color: tomato;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 firebrick, -2px -2px 0 firebrick, -3px -3px 0 firebrick, -4px -4px 0 firebrick, -5px -5px 0 firebrick, -6px -6px 0 firebrick, -7px -7px 0 firebrick, -8px -8px 0 firebrick, -30px 20px 40px dimgrey;
}

.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.delete {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<p id="first">Get it done today</p>
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<ul>
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```